Naive matrix addition vs expression template matrix addition performs better, allocation taken into account or not
This question is a follow up on questions Expression templates cppcon 2019 and matrix class with expression templates à la cppcon 2019
I finally coded a toy matrix class dense_matrix with expression templates as I initially wanted :
// I forward declare the class which all matrix classes will derive from
// as I need such a class matrix-related traits
class base_matrix;

//is_matrix_v
template <class T>
struct is_matrix
{
    static constexpr bool value = std::derived_from<T, base_matrix>;
};
template <class T>
struct is_matrix<std::vector<T>>
{
    // std::vector<T> will be considered as a column or row matrix according to its position in a multiplication
    static constexpr bool value = true;
};
template <class T>
constexpr bool is_matrix_v = is_matrix<std::remove_cvref_t<T>>::value;

struct expression {}; // you always need a base for traits right ?

// finally defining what is being a matrix or an expression
template <class T>
concept is_matrix_or_expression =
is_matrix_v<std::remove_cvref_t<T>>
||
std::is_base_of_v<expression, std::remove_cvref_t<T>>;

// defining what a legal binary matrix operation is
template <class A, class B>
constexpr bool is_matrix_binary_op_ok =
is_matrix_or_expression<A>
||
is_matrix_or_expression<B>;


//subscripts() for matrix(i,j)
template <class operand>
auto subscripts(operand const& v, size_t const i, size_t const j) {
    if constexpr (is_matrix_or_expression<operand>) {
        return v(i, j);
    }
    else {
        return v;
    }
}

template <class operand>
auto rows(operand const& m) {
    if constexpr (is_matrix_or_expression<operand>) {
        return m.rows();
    }
    else {
        return 1;
    }
};

template <class operand>
auto cols(operand const& m) {
    if constexpr (is_matrix_or_expression<operand>) {
        return m.cols();
    }
    else {
        return 1;
    }
};

The matrix template expression class, in the fashion of Bowie Owens' cppcon 2019 talk is using variadic operands to handle any-arity operator all at once :
template <class callable, class... operands>
class matrix_expression : public expression
{
    std::tuple<operands const &...> args_;
    callable f_;
public:
    matrix_expression(callable f, operands const&... args) : args_(args...), f_(f) {}

    auto& operator()(const size_t i, const size_t j)
    {
        auto const call_at_index_couple =
            [this, i, j](operands const&... a)
            {
                return f_(subscripts(a, i, j)...);
            };
        return std::apply(call_at_index_couple, args_);
    }

    auto operator()(const size_t i, const size_t j) const
    {
        auto const call_at_index_couple =
            [this, i, j](operands const&... a)
            {
                return f_(subscripts(a, i, j)...);
            };
        return std::apply(call_at_index_couple, args_);
    }

    size_t rows() const
    {
        auto const call_rows =
            [](operands const&... a)
            {
                return std::max(::rows(a)...);
            };
        return std::apply(call_rows, args_);
    }
    size_t cols() const
    {
        auto const call_cols =
            [](operands const&... a)
            {
                return std::max(::cols(a)...);
            };
        return std::apply(call_cols, args_);
    }

};

//defining addition
template <class LHS, class RHS, class = std::enable_if_t<is_matrix_binary_op_ok<LHS, RHS>>>
auto operator+(LHS const& lhs, RHS const& rhs)
{
    return matrix_expression
    {
        //[](auto a, auto b)
        //{
        //  return a + b;
        //}
        std::plus<>{},
        lhs,
        rhs
    };
}

// and substraction
template <class LHS, class RHS, class = std::enable_if_t<is_matrix_binary_op_ok<LHS, RHS>>>
auto operator-(LHS const& lhs, RHS const& rhs)
{
    return matrix_expression
    {
        //[](auto a, auto b)
        //{
        //    return a - b;
        //}
        std::minus<>{},
        lhs,
        rhs
    };
}

//finally defining the forward declared base_matrix
class base_matrix : public expression
{
public:
    virtual ~base_matrix() = default;
    //  So we can call matrix(i,j) ...
    virtual double& operator()(const size_t i, const size_t j) = 0;
    // ... and set matrix(i,j)
    virtual double operator()(const size_t i, const size_t j) const = 0;
    virtual size_t rows() const = 0;
    virtual size_t cols() const = 0;
};

//defining a simple and concrecte dense matrix class
class dense_matrix : public base_matrix
{
    size_t          rows_;
    size_t          columns_;
    std::vector<double>  underlying_vector_;
public:
    dense_matrix() : rows_(0), columns_(0) {}
    dense_matrix(const size_t rows, const size_t cols)
        : rows_(rows), columns_(cols), underlying_vector_(rows* cols) {}
    dense_matrix(const size_t rows, const size_t cols, double* ptr)
        : rows_(rows), columns_(cols), underlying_vector_(ptr, ptr + (rows * cols)) {}
    dense_matrix(std::vector<double>& vector, bool isColumn = true)
    {
        if (isColumn)
        {
            rows_ = vector.size();
            columns_ = 1;
        }
        else
        {
            rows_ = 1;
            columns_ = vector.size();
        }
        underlying_vector_ = std::move(vector);
    }

    template <class src_type>
    dense_matrix(const src_type& src)
        : rows_(src.rows()),
        columns_(src.cols()),
        underlying_vector_(src.rows()* src.cols())
    {
        for (size_t i = 0; i < src.rows(); ++i)
        {
            for (size_t j = 0; j < src.cols(); ++j)
            {
                underlying_vector_[i * columns_ + j] = src(i, j);
            }
        }
    }
    template <class src_type>
    dense_matrix& operator=(src_type const& src)
    {
        for (size_t i = 0; i < rows(); ++i)
        {
            for (size_t j = 0; j < cols(); ++j)
            {
                underlying_vector_[i * columns_ + j] = src(i, j);
            }
        }
        return *this; // this line was missing in the slides and in the talk
    }
    //  Access
    size_t rows() const override { return rows_; }
    size_t cols() const override { return columns_; }
    double& operator()(const size_t i, const size_t j) override
    {
        return underlying_vector_[i * columns_ + j];
    }
    double operator()(const size_t i, const size_t j) const override
    {
        return underlying_vector_[i * columns_ + j];
    }
};

I am ok for the short time being with this class, so that I wanted to test its performance for algebraic operations. Hence I coded a naive matrix class as follows :
class dense_matrix_naive
{
    size_t          rows_;
    size_t          columns_;
    std::vector<double>  underlying_vector_;
public:
    const std::vector<double>& underlying_vector() const { return underlying_vector_; }
    dense_matrix_naive() : rows_(0), columns_(0) {}
    dense_matrix_naive(const size_t rows, const size_t cols)
        : rows_(rows), columns_(cols), underlying_vector_(rows* cols) {}
    dense_matrix_naive(const size_t rows, const size_t cols, double* ptr)
        : rows_(rows), columns_(cols), underlying_vector_(ptr, ptr + (rows * cols)) {}
    dense_matrix_naive(std::vector<double>& vector, bool isColumn = true)
    {
        if (isColumn)
        {
            rows_ = vector.size();
            columns_ = 1;
        }
        else
        {
            rows_ = 1;
            columns_ = vector.size();
        }
        underlying_vector_ = std::move(vector);
    }

    template <class src_type>
    dense_matrix_naive(const src_type& src)
        : rows_(src.rows()),
        columns_(src.cols()),
        underlying_vector_(src.rows()* src.cols())
    {
        for (size_t i = 0; i < src.rows(); ++i)
        {
            for (size_t j = 0; j < src.cols(); ++j)
            {
                underlying_vector_[i * columns_ + j] = src(i, j);
            }
        }
    }
    template <class src_type>
    dense_matrix_naive& operator=(src_type const& src)
    {
        for (size_t i = 0; i < rows(); ++i)
        {
            for (size_t j = 0; j < cols(); ++j)
            {
                underlying_vector_[i * columns_ + j] = src(i, j);
            }
        }
        return *this; // this line was missing in the slides and in the talk
    }
    //  Access
    size_t rows() const { return rows_; }
    size_t cols() const { return columns_; }
    double& operator()(const size_t i, const size_t j)
    {
        return underlying_vector_[i * columns_ + j];
    }
    double operator()(const size_t i, const size_t j) const
    {
        return underlying_vector_[i * columns_ + j];
    }

    dense_matrix_naive& operator+=(const dense_matrix_naive& rhs)
    {
        for (size_t i = 0; i < underlying_vector_.size(); ++i)
        {
            underlying_vector_[i] += rhs.underlying_vector()[i];
        }
        return *this;
    }

    dense_matrix_naive& operator-=(const dense_matrix_naive& rhs)
    {
        for (size_t i = 0; i < underlying_vector_.size(); ++i)
        {
            underlying_vector_[i] -= rhs.underlying_vector()[i];
        }
        return *this;
    }
};

inline dense_matrix_naive operator+(const dense_matrix_naive& m1, const dense_matrix_naive& m2)
{
    auto res(m1);
    res += m2;
    return res;
}

inline dense_matrix_naive operator-(const dense_matrix_naive& m1, const dense_matrix_naive& m2)
{
    auto res(m1);
    res -= m2;
    return res;
}

Finally, the comparison test :

I perform a sum of 3 dense matrices, with and without expression templates
matrix coefficients are random doubles
I perform the sum a thousand times each and for various sizes of square matrices.
I do that in themain() function beneath
The function's source code is compiled using current last version 17.8.5 of microsoft visual studio professional 2022, with the C++ compiler "Visual C++ 2022   00476-80000-00000-AA747" and with the following command :

/permissive- /ifcOutput "x64\Release\" /GS /GL /W3 /Gy /Zc:wchar_t /Zi /Gm- /O2 /sdl /Fd"x64\Release\vc143.pdb" /Zc:inline /D "NDEBUG" /D "_CONSOLE" /D "_UNICODE" /D  "UNICODE" /errorReport:prompt /WX- /Zc:forScope /Gd /Oi /MD /std:c++latest /FC  /Fa"x64\Release\" /EHsc /nologo /Fo"x64\Release\" /Ot  /Fp"x64\Release\ConsoleApplication1.pch" /diagnostics:column
The main() source code is :
int main()
{
    constexpr size_t nb_ops = 1000;

    constexpr size_t square_matrix_sizes[] = { 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90,
                                    100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 600, 700, 800, 900,
                                    1000, 5000};


    std::cout << "SIZE" << '\t' << '\t' << "NAIVE" << '\t' << '\t' << "EXPR" << "\n";
    for (const auto square_matrix_size : square_matrix_sizes)
    {

        // Setting data
        //constexpr size_t square_matrix_size = 800;
        typedef std::mt19937 MyRNG;
        uint32_t seed_val = 1729;
        MyRNG rng;
        rng.seed(seed_val);
        std::normal_distribution<double> normal_dist(0.0, 1.0);

        dense_matrix_naive m1_naive(square_matrix_size, square_matrix_size);
        for (size_t i = 0; i < square_matrix_size; ++i)
        {
            for (size_t j = 0; j < square_matrix_size; ++j)
            {
                m1_naive(i, j) = normal_dist(rng);
            }
        }
        dense_matrix_naive m2_naive(square_matrix_size, square_matrix_size);
        for (size_t i = 0; i < square_matrix_size; ++i)
        {
            for (size_t j = 0; j < square_matrix_size; ++j)
            {
                m2_naive(i, j) = normal_dist(rng);
            }
        }
        dense_matrix_naive m3_naive(square_matrix_size, square_matrix_size);
        for (size_t i = 0; i < square_matrix_size; ++i)
        {
            for (size_t j = 0; j < square_matrix_size; ++j)
            {
                m3_naive(i, j) = normal_dist(rng);
            }
        }

        dense_matrix m1(square_matrix_size, square_matrix_size);
        for (size_t i = 0; i < square_matrix_size; ++i)
        {
            for (size_t j = 0; j < square_matrix_size; ++j)
            {
                m1(i, j) = normal_dist(rng);
            }
        }
        dense_matrix m2(square_matrix_size, square_matrix_size);
        for (size_t i = 0; i < square_matrix_size; ++i)
        {
            for (size_t j = 0; j < square_matrix_size; ++j)
            {
                m2(i, j) = normal_dist(rng);
            }
        }
        dense_matrix m3(square_matrix_size, square_matrix_size);
        for (size_t i = 0; i < square_matrix_size; ++i)
        {
            for (size_t j = 0; j < square_matrix_size; ++j)
            {
                m3(i, j) = normal_dist(rng);
            }
        }

        auto start = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
        for (size_t i = 0; i < nb_ops; ++i)
        {
            dense_matrix_naive m4_naive = m1_naive + m2_naive + m3_naive;
        }
        auto end = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
        std::chrono::duration<double> elapsed_seconds = end - start;
        std::cout << square_matrix_size << '\t' << '\t' << std::fixed << elapsed_seconds << '\t';

        start = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
        for (size_t i = 0; i < nb_ops; ++i)
        {

            dense_matrix m4 = m1 + m2 + m3;
        }
        end = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
        elapsed_seconds = end - start;
        std::cout << std::fixed << elapsed_seconds << "\n";
    }
    

This main() prints something in this fashion :
SIZE            NAIVE           EXPR
10              0.001863s       0.000990s
20              0.001125s       0.003765s
30              0.002650s       0.010777s
40              0.002999s       0.022661s
50              0.005942s       0.029157s
60              0.008142s       0.030399s
70              0.008975s       0.051088s
80              0.085463s       0.065621s
90              0.071054s       0.085647s
100             0.042847s       0.109610s
200             0.116581s       0.385381s
300             0.927886s       0.719902s
400             1.030033s       1.617557s
500             1.595740s       2.577250s
600             2.553515s       3.609214s
700             3.650004s       4.948367s
800             4.860585s       6.840540s
900             6.040074s       8.451447s
1000            7.586206s       10.528636s
5000            196.896556s     259.612446s

As soon as the size of matrices is sufficiently significant so that there are enough operations to be performed, the naïve implementation is quasi-systematically executed faster that the one using expression templates, which is not what I expected.

There is virtual call difference too...

@Jarod42 if you add a base class in the naive case, there will also be a virtual call too yet the perfs will still be the same.

I don't think your compiler can completely devirtualize your expression code, causing runtime dispatch overhead that the compiler can't optimize away. Expression templates only work well if you use compile-time only features such as CRTP, or if you wanted to do this in a way more modern manner, you could try designing this with concepts + deducing this in the base class (P0847 in C++23).

@11house Even if you add a base class to the "naive" case: you have only a single virtual dispatch for the entire operation, while in your expression case you have that dispatch for each individual matrix element.

@chris_se You are right about virtual calls order of magnitude. Regarding the CRTP the cppcon speaker (Bowie Owens) was advocating variadic over CRTP to be able to tackle all arity operators at once, without (as far as I remember) addressing performance, wow that you mention it. How could I set up CRTP here, is it easy ? And with concepts ? Pointers (lol) appreciated

Why are you using virtual with expression templates?

CRTP itself is not complicated in and by itself, but it is quite cumbersome and verbose. It replaces virtual inheritance when everything can be resolved at compile time. You can find a ton of tutorials online about how it works. That all said: there are already quite a few linear algebra libraries for C++ out there (e.g. Eigen, boost::ublas, Armadillo, Fastor, etc.), so you might want to peek at those to see how this can be done. (All have their corresponding downsides and legacy design decisions.)

If you must use virtual, use final to ensure devirtualization is easy.  But with properly written expression templates you shouldn't need virtual dispatch, and if you do need virtual dispatch then your expression templates are written wrong.

Your operator+ in the expression template case does maximally non-contiguous memory access.  It also treats "2" like ((2,2),(2,2)) not ((2,0),(0,2)) in that your subscripts seems off.

operator+(const dense_matrix_naive& m1, const dense_matrix_naive& m2) should be dense_matrix_naive operator+(dense_matrix_naive m1, const dense_matrix_naive& m2) { m1 += m2; return m1; } as that permits some RVO/elision optimizations yours does not; namely a+b+c becomes (a+b)+c, and the temporary a+b is reused as the lhs of +c.  For longer expressions this can be significant.

@Yakk-AdamNevraumont My line of thought for using virtual was the following : I need to have a top matrix class which all matrix classes will derive from as this top class is needed to characterize "being a matrix" with traits, and I decided that I want that top class to be pure abstract.

@Yakk-AdamNevraumont I don't get you final comment, nor the one regarding  maximally non-contiguous memory access (I know what it is, but I don't see how it would be avoidable in the template case as I implemented it)

@Yakk-AdamNevraumont for what the naive operator+ should be, isn't it a problem that m1 is non const ? I find it bizarre that an addition can change the first operand.

@11house It can change a copy of the first argument.  By-value argument is a copy.

@Yakk-AdamNevraumont for some reason my brain made me see an & in the first argument when there wasn't, sorry.

Your "naive" solution over-allocates buffers.  But memory allocation in modern OS's cost doesn't scale with the size of the allocation.  So you end up with a needless overhead on it, but that overhead doesn't scale with the size of the matrix.
You can get a substantial speedup by doing this:
inline dense_matrix_naive operator+(dense_matrix_naive m1, constdense_matrix_naive& m2)
{
  m1 += m2;
  return m1;
}

and adding move/copy semantics:
dense_matrix_naive(dense_matrix_naive&&)=default;
dense_matrix_naive& operator=(dense_matrix_naive&&)& =default;
// optional, I sometimes skip them because they are expensive and require
// explicit .copy() method calls:
// dense_matrix_naive(dense_matrix_naive const&)=default;
// dense_matrix_naive& operator=(dense_matrix_naive const&)& =default;

Before hand, if we did:
dense_matrix_naive foo = m1 + m2 + m3;

this is parsed as:
dense_matrix_naive foo = (m1 + m2) + m3

now, your (m1 + m2) allocates a buffer and stores the result into it.  Call this tmp:
auto tmp = m1+m2;
dense_matrix_naive foo = std::move(tmp) + m3

in this step, we then allocate another temporary and store tmp+m3 in it:
auto tmp = m1+m2;
auto tmp2 = std::move(tmp)+m3;
dense_matrix_naive foo = std::move(tmp2);

The constructor for foo then allocates yet another buffer, then copies the elements of tmp2 over to it.
Finally, tmp and tmp2 are cleaned up.
With my variant the same parsing happens:
auto tmp = m1+m2;
auto tmp2 = std::move(tmp)+m3;
dense_matrix_naive foo = std::move(tmp2);

but the code is designed to do it optimally.
auto tmp = m1+m2;

here, we copy m1 into a temporary, then we add m2 to that temporary using +=, then we store it in tmp without further copies.
auto tmp2 = std::move(tmp)+m3;

here, we move tmp into the first argument of + (which is a value, so accepts moves, not a const& that ignores them).  We then increment the values += by m3's values, and then using implicit move we directly store that in tmp2 without a buffer allocation.
In the original, we had allocated 2 buffers by this point -- in the rewritten, we have allocated only 1.  No buffers are allocated in tmp2 calculation because we end up reusing tmp's buffer (as we know it will be never used again before it is discarded).
dense_matrix_naive foo = tmp2;

and because we have dense_matrix_naive(dense_matrix_naive&&) = default; constructor, this is a free operation.  tmp2 just becomes foo.
X operator+(X const& lhs, X const& rhs) {
  X tmp = lhs;
  tmp+=rhs;
  return tmp;
}

this is an anti-pattern, while
X operator+(X lhs, X const& rhs) {
  lhs+=rhs;
  return lhs;
}

is never worse and usually better.  By taking the lhs argument by value, we move the copy to the tmp into a spot that the caller can know about it.  And because of how a+b+c+d+e is handled by C++ it lets us reuse buffers that the other version could not.
...
So that in detail explains why at small sizes your expression template version is faster.  We are avoiding 1 or 2 (I'd have to double check) calls to malloc.
Once your buffers become large, then the fact that your naive implementation is cache-friendly makes a bigger difference.
In both cases, we have your blocks of memory:
a b c d     a b c d
e f g h     e f g h
i j k l  +  i j k l
m n o p     m n o p

The naive version ends up iterating over this memory in order it is stored in RAM.  We take the top left lhs += the top left on the rhs, then the next one, etc.  When the matrixes are 5000 wide and 5000 tall, we iterate over 100,000,000 bytes of memory like two marching ants.
After a bit of inlining, converting that into SIMD instructions is trivial.
In the expression template case:
a b c d     a b c d     a b c d
e f g h     e f g h     e f g h
i j k l  +  i j k l  +  i j k l
m n o p     m n o p     m n o p

we grab the 3 top left elements and store it in a 4th buffer.  Then we grab the b elements and store it in the 4th buffer.
Each of the element accesses is through a virtual function, which can slow things down or block inlining.
Making a SIMD (lhs[i]+=rhs[i]) is trivial.  Making a SIMD(lhs[i]=rhs0[i]+rhs1[i]+rhs2[i]) is much harder.
What more, this operation iterates over 400,000,000 bytes of data total, instead of 200,000,000, and does it along 4 different paths instead of 2.  This harms cache coherency.
Now, the naive one with extra buffers ends up touching more memory in total, so that would be an edge to the expression template one - but the cache coherency and SIMD-ability carries the day.
One idea for your expression templates is to rely on repeated looped += instead of one + loop.  And maybe make your expression template do a row at a time, instead of an element at time.
To that end, a .get_row( int row_num, T* ) method on your expression template could work.
void get_row( int row_num, T* zeroed_output ) const {
  const auto columns = cols();
  auto incremental = [row_num, zeroed_output, columns](auto& rhs) {
    for (int col_num = 0; col_num < columns; ++col_num) {
      zeroed_output[col_num] = f(zeroed_output[col_num], subscripts(rhs, row_nom, col_num));
    }
  };
  std::apply([&incremental](auto...&& rhs) {
    (incremental(rhs), ...);
  }, args_ );
}

the goal here is to increase cache-coherency on the operation and make it as easy to SIMD optimize as possible.
Then in the constructor for your matrix class, you fetch values from the rhs one row at a time (directly into your output buffer).
...
But really get rid of that virtual stuff, especially during testing.

I will try to digest that tonight, thank you.

For size 500 square matrices passing the first argument by copy indeed speeded up the sum from 1.4s to 0.85s. Yet introducing dense_matrix_naive(dense_matrix_naive&&) = default; or (hence both) dense_matrix_naive& operator=(dense_matrix_naive&&)& = default; introduced an Error C2280 'dense_matrix_naive::dense_matrix_naive(const dense_matrix_naive &)': attempting to reference a deleted function on dense_matrix_naive m4_naive = m1_naive + m2_naive + m3_naive;

@11house Looks like we need a const ref ctor as well, as that expressiin requires 1 copy.

That's what I don't get, I already have the template <class src_type> dense_matrix_naive(const src_type& src)

@11house Special member functions are not replaced by templates.

In fact in my previous question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78289192/matrix-class-with-expression-templates-%c3%a0-la-cppcon-2019 I already tried to implement your get_row suggestion (in the double * operator[] (int row) fashion though) without success

@11house double* operator[](int row) was not my suggestion.  That requires a pre-persistent buffer containing the row to always exist with exactly the data.  My suggestion requires the consumer to provide a place to put the result.  The point of my suggestion is to allow SIMD instructions to be used to calculate a batch of data on demand, which your current solution does not.  Your "return a buffer" in turn requires that the data be cached in the source for an indeterminate period.  In any case, good luck.

Ok, I see, thank you. I any case I don't think it would improve the variadic expr templates version that much for it to be able to compete with the naïve one. I am into implementing a CRTP one¨.

I mean, I believe you are wrong, but you do you.

I don't know why I argue as you are right. :) I indeed understand now your answer, except for one thing : "rely on repeated looped += instead of one + loop".

@11house I am not saying I am right, I just think trying it is a good idea.  In the naive case your code loops over 50005000 in parallel with 50005000, then does it 3 more times, to get the answer.  In the non-naive case, it iterates over 50005000, 50005000, 50005000, 50005000 in one big loop, incrementing all 4 pointers.  This could have difficult to understand implications on cache coherency and on what SIMD instructions your compiler generates.  The get_row(T*, int) function is intended to allow for SIMD code generation in non-naive to be similar to naive.

I just tested the get_row idea and now the "variadic" expression template based case (with get_row) execution is just a bit slower than the naive one (with your SIMD optimization) : for 250 operations on size 1000 squared matrice before I had on average 0.003827s vs 0.007110s while I now have 0.003919s vs 0.004849s. As I said, there's only one thing remaining unclear : the "rely on repeated looped += instead of one + loop" bit. (Also, as you seem to be well-versed on the subject, would you have book reference on that kind of questions pls?)

Sorry to insist, but as I am not a native english speaker I fail to understand if "maybe make your expression template do a row at a time, instead of an element at time" is a concrete realization of the idea "rely on repeated looped += instead of one + loop", or if rely on repeated looped += instead of one + loop" and "make your expression template do a row at a time, instead of an element at time" are independent - in which case I fail to see how to rely on repeated += loop, except by fragmenting the matrices in "contiguous" blocks and doing a block sum : is the the idea?
